How to run MSBuild command to build VS solution using a GitLab runner with shell executor and PowerShell as shell?
When it comes to VS Studio I am a "click here and there" type of person when it comes to building most of my projects. Now I am trying to use my own GitLab runner to build a solution that contains multiple projects.
The runner's executor is set to shell with powershell as the shell.
The CI job looks like this:
stages:
  - build

variables:
  msbuild: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'

build-deps:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - winsrv2016
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_PATHS: deps/*
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
    exclude:
      - build\*\*.o
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cmake.exe -Bbuild -DBUILD_DEPS=ON
    - echo $env:PATH
    - echo $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - $msbuild $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln

The job fails with the following (roughly translated since the original message is in German) error:
In line:290 character:10
+ $msbuild $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token "$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln" in expression or 
instruction.
In line:290 character:29
+ $msbuild $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token "\build\myproject.sln" in expression or instruction.
In line:1 character:3
+ & {
+   ~
The closing "}" is missing in expression block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
In line:1 character:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token "}" in expression or instruction.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 

I tried using absolute path, changing the slashes (I am used to Linux so on Windows I always make errors with path notation) etc. From what I know PowerShell is slash-agnostic (doesn't matter if you use / or \ for path separation).
My project is using CMake, which I have installed on the system where the runner is operating and it is accessible in PowerShell. I do not see any errors during the CMake configuration step.

To simplify things I would suggest to use the build tool mode of CMake. cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD --config Release This uses the native build tool of the platform. For Windows this is MSBuild.

Thank you. I will do that for this case in particular. However, I would still like to know how to fix this in case I want to actually run not only MSBuild but other things as well. Digging into the very limited documentation of GitLab on shell executors, I found out that it explicitly says "Powershell scripts". This made me believe that I can only run ps1 files that in terms would invoke the commands I need. That said, the fact I can run cmake.exe does tell a different story. So it's something about the syntax here that I don't understand.

$msbuild does not seem to be a valid powershell variable. The error command tries to express that a statement in the form $var = value is expected. It either does not exist or is empty.

$msbuild is a variable I have defined in the global variables section of CI config file. I will add this to the question. Sorry. I also noticed that I am getting errors with the suggested cmake --build ... call in one of the dependencies (Assimp in my case) so I guess it is not a "run and done" case either. :D

A typical programm call in Powershell is either with a leading ampersand, i.e. & "msbuild" $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln  or by using start-program commandlet, i.e. Start-Process -FilePath "$msbuild" -ArgumentList "$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\build\myproject.sln". PS: You can use script blocks by entering - | in the first line after script keyword. every following line is indented up to the | and followed by powershell commands.
